# Sending React data to an Express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-hooks

**Context:** I try to use Hooks and State in React to do some conditional rendering to get data then send data to an Express server and save it in a MongoDB Database.

**Problem:** When checking the data in Mongo it shows any data.

**What I am stuck with:**

1. I think that the Hook that I use to get input from the front-end is missing some key parts (the "value" attribute at each component is what I can think of)
2. I tried using the "checkbox" instead of the "radio" button for conditional rendering other components but could not achieve the same result but using "radio" which also prevent me from using the input for a control component.

#### New Task.js

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Button from "./Button";
import './NewTask.css';
import TaskDetails from "./TaskDetails";
import TaskSetting from "./TaskSetting";
import Task from './Task';

const NewTask = () => {
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState("inPerson");
    const [data, setData] = useState({
        taskType: '',
        taskTitle: '',
        taskDesc: '',
        suburbInput: '',
        dateInput: ''
    })


    const handleCheck = (event) => {
        const {value,name} = event.target
        setChecked(value)   
        setData( (preValue) => {
            return{
                ...preValue,
                [name]:value
            }
        })      
    }



    const handleClick = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:4000/register', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                taskType: data.taskType,
                taskTitle: data.taskTitle,
                taskDesc: data.taskDesc,
                suburb: data.suburbInput,
                date: data.dateInput
            })
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data))
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("Error:" + err)
            })

    }


    return (
        <div className="newtask-div">
            <h3 className="header">New Task</h3>
            <ul className="task-item">
                <li style={{ fontSize: "17px" }}>Select Task Type: </li>
                <li>
                    <Task
                        type="radio"
                        name="taskType"
                        checked={checked === "inPerson"}
                        value="inPerson"
                        onChange={handleCheck}
                        lable="In person"
                    />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Task
                        type="radio"
                        checked={checked === "online"}
                        name="taskType"
                        value="online"
                        onChange={handleCheck}
                        lable="Online"
                    />
                </li>
            </ul>


            <h3 className="header">Describe your Task to Experts</h3>
            <TaskDetails
                text="Task Title"
                type="text"
                name="taskTitle"
                value={data.taskTitle}
                onChange={handleCheck}
                placeholder="Enter task title"
                style={{
                    width: "50%",
                    height: "30px",
                    padding: "10px 15px",
                }}
            />
            <TaskDetails
                text="Description"
                type="text"
                name="taskDesc"
                value={data.taskDesc}
                onChange={handleCheck}
                placeholder="Enter task description"
                style={{
                    width: "50%",
                    height: "50px",
                    padding: "10px 15px",
                    margin: "0 0 0 -15px"
                }}
            />

            {/* Conditional rendering with radio button */}
            <h3 className="header">Setting up your Task</h3>
            {checked === "inPerson"
                &&
                <div className="setting-div">
                    <TaskSetting
                        text="Suburb"
                        type="text"
                        name="suburbInput"
                        value={data.suburbInput}
                        onChange={handleCheck}
                        placeholder="Enter a suburb"
                        style={{
                            width: "50%",
                            height: "20px",
                            padding: "10px 15px",
                            margin: "10px 15px"
                        }}
                    />
                    <TaskSetting
                        text="Date"
                        type="date"
                        name="dateInput"
                        value={data.dateInput}
                        onChange={handleCheck}
                        style={{
                            width: "10%",
                            height: "20px",
                            padding: "10px",
                            margin: "10px 30px"
                        }}
                    />
                </div>
            }

            {checked === "online"
                &&
                <div className="setting-div">
                    <TaskSetting
                        text="Date"
                        type="date"
                        name="date-input"
                        value={data.dateInput}
                        onChange={handleCheck}
                        style={{
                            width: "10%",
                            height: "20px",
                            padding: "10px",
                            margin: "10px 30px"
                        }}
                    />
                </div>
            }


            {/* Send data to sever */}
            <Button
                type="submit"
                text="Post a Task"
                onClick={handleClick}
                style={{
                    color: "black",
                    margin: "40px",
                    padding: "10pX 20px",
                    display: "inline-block"
                }}
            />

            <p>{data.taskType}</p>
            <p>{data.taskTitle}</p>

        </div>
    )
}


export default NewTask
```

#### Server.js

```js
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const validator = require("validator");
const Task = require("./models/Task");
const cors = require("cors");


const app = express();



app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(cors())

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/TaskDB", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})


app.get('/', (req,res) =>{
    const task = {
        taskType: "online",
        taskTitle: "Building Website",
        taskDesc: "Build a good website",
        suburb: "burwood",
        date: "09/10/2021"
    }
    res.send(task)

})

app.post('/register', (req,res) =>{

    const task = new Task({
        taskType : req.body.taskType,
        taskTitle : req.body.taskTitle,
        taskDesc : req.body.taskDesc,
        suburb : req.body.suburbInput,
        date: req.body.dateInput
    });
    task.save()
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    res.json(('save to db: ' + task));
})


app.listen(4000, (req,res)=>{
    console.log("server is running on port 4000");
})
```

Comment: Maybe you need to replace that: .then(data => console.log(data)) for that .then(data => setData(data))? also, does the express/mongo server works? did you tried in postman? I mean, I struggle to understand if you are having issues in react or in your API.

Comment: Im quite sure the problem is from react.

Comment: try to check "network" tab in your browser inspect and check the API calling for "/register", check the body and be sure that the client-side has the issue, and then give me the feedback.

Comment: In route "register" let me know the output for console.log(req.body);

Comment: @Bharath it returns empty as well

Comment: I just updated with what I have done so far. Basically, i made another hook for entering input. It worked. However, another problem is when the radio is "ticked" and I tried entering other input (Description, title,...) React re-render the page. Any method to avoid this ?

Comment: @Bharath @novomino I added `app.use(bodyParser.json())` to sever,js and it worked now